# Lossless Join Decomposition Property

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have the following relational schema R with the given functional dependencies. Since, R is not in BCNF, I'm trying to find its loseless join decomposition. Anyone have any idea how I can approach this. Thanks in advance!

```
R (SSN, PersonNo, CourseNo, Semester, FacultyName, PersonName, CourseTitle, Credit, Grade)

Functional Dependencies are as follows: 

SSN -> FacultyName;
PersonNo -> PersonName;
CourseNo -> CourseTitle;
(CourseNo, Semester) -> (SSN, Credit);
(CourseNo, Semester, PersonNo) -> Grade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the standard normalization is all that is called for. The relation seems to be trivially in 1nf so first, from the POV of the student, taking multiple courses means that everything involved with the course is repeated. This implies R1( PersonNo, PersonName ) and R2( PersonNo, SSN, CourseNo, Semester, FacultyName, CourseTitle, Credit, Grade ). Now R1 is in 2nf and so far it is lossless: R1 X R2 = R.

Repeat now with R2 from the POV of the course. Every instantiation means that the semester it is taught in, the instructor teaching it and the student taking it are duplicated, implying R2( CourseNo, CourseTitle ) and R3( CourseNo, PersonNo, SSN, Semester, FacultyName, Credit, Grade ).

To quickly continue: R3 is normalized to R3( SSN, FacultyName ), R4( SSN, CourseNo, Semester, PersonNo, Credit, Grade ).

Finally to 3nf with R4 to R4( CourseNo, Semester, PersonNo ), R5( CourseNo, Semester, PersonNo, Grade ) and R6( CourseNo, Semester ), R7( CourseNo, Semester, SSN, Credit ).

This is all worked out by hand so there could be a discrepancy or two. But it all looks like this devolves into four entity tables: People, Faculty, Courses, Classes and three intersection tables PersonClass (with Grade as attribute of the relationship), FacultyClass (with Credit as attribute of the relationship) and CourseClass.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like People X PersonClass X Faculty X FacultyClass X Courses X CourseClass X Classes gets back the original R.

So the whole thing is lossless.

As it should be.

Unless I've completely missed something important...